# Stack Paren Checker Not Working in C Code

Tags: c

I am attempting to build a parenthesis checker in C using a homebuilt stack, but the stack is an array that prevents my program from working by returning an array of random numbers. Please assist.

```
#define STACK_SIZE 100
#include <stdio.h>

char stack[STACK_SIZE];
int sp=0;

/*
 * Pushes character c onto the stack.
 * Returns 0 if successful.
 * Returns -1 if an error occurs.  (Stack full).
 */
int push (char c)
{
    if (sp >= STACK_SIZE) {
        printf("c");
        return -1;
    }
    else {
        stack[sp] = c;
        sp++;
        return 0;
    }
}

/*
 * Pops next character off the stack.
 * Returns the char if successful.
 * Returns -1 if an error occurs.  (Stack empty).
 */
int pop ()
{
    if (sp == 0) {
        return -1;
    }
    else {
        sp--;
        return stack[sp];
    }
}

/*
 * Returns the current size of the stack.
 */
int stackSize()
{
    printf("%i", sp);
    return sp;
}

void printStack()
{
    //TODO
}
int main ()
{
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
        stack[i] = 0;
    }

    int null = 0;
    char b;
    char a = getchar();
    while (a != EOF) {
        if (a == '(') {
            if (stackSize() >= 100) {
                printf("Error. Stack Full!\n");
                return -1;
            }
            push(')');
        }
        else if (a == '{') {
            if (stackSize() >= 100) {
                printf("Error. Stack Full!\n");
                return 1;
            }
            push('}');
        }
        else if (a == '[') {
            if (stackSize() >= 100) {
                printf("Error. Stack Full!\n");
                return 1;
            }
            push(']');
        }
        else if (a == ')') {
            b = pop();
            if (stackSize() == 0) {
                printf("Found %c. No matching character\n", a);
                return 2;
            }
            else if (a != b) {
                printf("Found %c, expected ).\n", a);
                return 2;
            }
        }
        else if (a == '}') {
            b = pop();
            if (stackSize() == 0) {
                printf("Found %c. No matching character\n", a);
                return 2;
            }
            else if (a != b) {
                printf("Found %c, expected }.\n", a);
                return 2;
            }
        }
        else if (a == ']') {
            b = pop();
            if (stackSize() == 0) {
                printf("Found %c. No matching character\n", a);
                return 2;
            }
            else if (a != b) {
                printf("Found %c, expected ].\n", a);
                return 2;
            }
        }
    }
    if (stackSize() != 0) {
        printf("Expecting %c, found end of input.\n", a);
        return 3;
    }
    printf("Well formatted input.\n");
    return 4;
}
```

Once I use a file as input, the program spits out roughly 100 random numbers and the "Error. Stack Full!" message. I can not get around this. Any help is welcomed and would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: Have you tried to debug it?

Comment: When you use a debugger, what is the *first* point at which the program behaves differently than expected?

Comment: You're missing a `}` somewhere.

Comment: I dont have a debugger in the linux nano editor, but it returns at the print statement for the stack full line.

Comment: In Linux you have `gdb`

Comment: i mistakenly duplicated two lines in the stack overflow question. The error remains but thank you for noticing that!

Comment: ok i will try gdb

Comment: `char a = getchar();` should be `int a = getchar();`

Comment: You have an infinite loop. You never reassign `a`, so you keep processing the same character forever.

Comment: You don't need to check the stack size before every push since you already check in the push function.

Comment: i am rather unexperienced in c so i do not understand fully how to use this gdb. Please help. Thank you!

Comment: Oh my god thank you very much Barmar your answer helped me solve the issue! I truly appreciate it!

Comment: [How to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)

Comment: Your code for `)` `}` and `]` is identical, you should combine them: `else if (a == ')' || a == '}' || a == ']')`